# iOS unable to see last few rows of custom table cell when scrolling to the bottom.

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, custom-controls

Currently I have a UITableview, I have enough data that cannot be shown entirely on the screen, so user will have to scroll the table view.

The issue I'm seeing is that when I scroll all the way to the bottom, the last element shown in the table view is not really the last element
however, if I do a touch drag, and try to drag it down really hard, I can see the last element, but if I release the finger, the scroll bounced back to the element that is displayed at the bottom, but not the last element

How can I ensure tableview scroll size is really same height as the container?

I did override the two methods:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I can make:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Really high, but still, when scroll down to the bottom, it is not the last element.

Comment: Do you have a toolbar at the bottom blocking the last row or is it totally off the screen?

Comment: no toolbar, just a tableview all to itself...this is on ipad..there is no navigation beneath the tableview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try reducing the height of the table view frame. that should do the trick.

as a starter, try reducing it by half and then if everything works fine try to calculate the necessary height.

Comment: hi ahsan, thanks for your reply, that worked, but i can't reduce the height or half, i need to make it to a specific height like the design says

Comment: well, i meant, if its current height is 100 make it 50 or so. Anyways, happy that it worked. Kindly accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check your table view's frame. If you have a navigation bar at the top your table view may be getting pushed down to accommodate it and your frame is too tall. Try reducing your table view's height.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this. Remove this.

```
 self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
```